# How to replace <img> including class attribute "size-full" with <picture> element from post content WordPress using regular expression?

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress, image

I am developing my custom theme and trying to figure out how to modify the default code for WordPress `<img>` inserted into the post content, so I could add support for webP format and have it within `<picture>` element.

I cannot get it working with regex.

Currently, my post content has got  element to display the thumbnail within `<p>` tag, but the `<img>` tag is a link `<a>` which points to the full-size image.

Currently I have got this for full-size image in the post content:

```
<p>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image-full.jpg" itemprop="url" title="Some title">
        <img alt="Alt tag of the image" class="alignnone size-full" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image-thumb.jpg" width="940" height="529">
    </a>
</p>
```

I am trying to modify it to get this as result:

```
<p>
    <a href="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image-full.jpg" itemprop="url" title="Some title">
        <picture>
            <source srcset="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image-thumb.webp" type="image/webp" />
            <img alt="Alt tag of the image" class="alignnone size-full" src="http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/image-thumb.jpg" width="940" height="529">
        </picture>
    </a>
</p>
```

I have one or more images inserted like this. So, would need to check the whole post content and somehow modify/replace this by finding the  with class having "size-full" and then for them add  around?

Should I use some `preg_replace()` or any function?

Maybe using some filter?

Do you have any ideas how to change it?

Comment: Why not use JavaScript and DOM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop through all images inside `$post` `the_content()` using `foreach()`.

Which gives us, `regex` for group matching of `<img>` tag. Put all images into `array()`.

Start counting from `-1` since `0` has the 1st image already in `array()`.

Loop through `array()` with images, find image with `"size-full"` with group match `3`, if yes, get it's `src` value with group match `7`.

After, replace `src="value"` extenstion - .png, .jpg ..., assign the replaced string to new variable. Use the new variable and add extension `".webp"` to the it.

Replace existing `<img>` tags with `<picture>` element and call the function on `$content`.

```
function webp_picture_fix($content){
    global $post;
    preg_match_all("/<img(.*?)class=('|\")(.*?)('|\")(.*?)src=('|\")(.*?)('|\")(.*?)>/i", $content, $images);

    if(!is_null($images)){
        $i = -1;
        foreach ($images as $key) {
            $i++;
            //echo $key[$i];
            if(strpos($images[3][$i], 'size-full') !== false){
                //echo "hi";
                $slika_ekstenzija = $images[7][$i];
                $sewebp = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $slika_ekstenzija);
                $webp_slika_src = $sewebp.".webp";
                $replacement = '<picture><source srcset="'.$webp_slika_src.'" type="image/webp" /><img'.$images[1][$i].'class='.$images[2][$i].$images[3][$i].$images[4][$i].$images[5][$i].'src='.$images[6][$i].$images[7][$i].$images[8][$i].$images[9][$i].'></picture>';
                $content = str_replace($images[0][$i], $replacement, $content);
            }
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'webp_picture_fix', 9999);
```